# How to read VMware snapshot data alone

Tags: vmware

I am using the following VDDK function to read VMware snapshot disk

http://bigchainring.kicks-ass.net/functions/VixDiskLib_Read.html

But it reads the complete disk sectors including empty spaces.
I need to backup only the data written to snapshot disk.
This is to save the backup disk space (eg If 126 KB snapshot is written in 40GB snapshot disk, then we need to read only 126 KB data and not 40 GB disk).
Please suggest the right way to read the data written to snapshot disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vSphere API `QueryChangedDiskAreas()` can be used with `changeId` parameter as `"*"` to retrieve the sector details which contains the data.

`VixDiskLib_Read()` can be used then to read the sectors from virtual disk.